# SQL Update child's key when there is a parent key is present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a **Table** of parent and child categories. I have been able to write a merge query to insert unique categories into the **Output** table. However I am having difficulties in how can I replace the child's cat_id with the parents so that they are tied to them.

```html
CREATE TABLE import_desctemp(
   TempID INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Main   nvarchar(10) NOT NULL
  ,Sub1   nvarchar(10)
  ,Sub2   nvarchar(10)
  ,cst    INT 
);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (TempID,'Main','Sub1','Sub2',cst);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (1,'Commercial','Bathroom',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (2,'Commercial','Kitchen','Pantry',NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (3,'Commercial','Kitchen','Pantry',NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (4,'Commercial','Rumpus',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (5,'Commercial','Rumpus',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (6,'Commercial',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (7,'Commercial',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (8,'Commercial',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (9,'Domestic','Bathroom','Toilet',NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (10,'Domestic','Bathroom','Toilet',NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (11,'Domestic','Bathroom','Toilet',NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (12,'Domestic','Bathroom',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (13,'Domestic','Kitchen',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (14,'Domestic','Kitchen',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (15,'Domestic','Laundry',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (16,'Domestic','Laundry',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (17,'Domestic','Laundry',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (18,'Domestic',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO import_desctemp(TempID,Main,Sub1,Sub2,cst) VALUES (19,'Domestic',NULL,NULL,NULL);


CREATE TABLE Description_Category(
   CSD_ID         INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Category       nvarchar(10)
  ,Parent_ID      INT
  ,Primary_cat_id INT
);
INSERT INTO Description_Category(CSD_ID,Category,Parent_ID,Primary_cat_id) VALUES (0,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Here is the code that I wrote. It is able to insert categories from the **import_desctemp** table into **Description_Category**
Just having issues with inserting the correct IDs into Primary_cat_ID so that it will reference the Parent category.

```html
--ALTER TABLE import_desctemp ADD CST int

DECLARE @MergeOutput1 table
(
  ActionType NVARCHAR(10),
  csd INT,
  cat nvarchar(10))

MERGE Description_Category AS C
USING  (
SELECT Main -- Do a group by to eliminate duplicates
FROM import_desctemp I
WHERE Main IS NOT null
GROUP BY Main
) AS SRC
ON (1=0)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
-- Insert Categories from excel table to live table
INSERT (category)
VALUES (Main)

OUTPUT
    $ACTION,
    INSERTED.CSD_ID,
    INSERTED.category
INTO @MergeOutput1;

MERGE Description_Category AS C
USING  (
SELECT DISTINCT Main, Sub1
FROM import_desctemp
WHERE sub1 is not null
GROUP BY Main, Sub1
) AS SRC
ON (1=0)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
-- Insert Categories from excel table to live table
INSERT (Category)
VALUES (Sub1)
OUTPUT
    $ACTION,
    INSERTED.CSD_ID,
    INSERTED.Category
INTO @MergeOutput1;

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT t.csd, t.cat--, c.csd_id as cat_id
FROM @MergeOutput1 t 
INNER JOIN import_desctemp c
ON c.Main = t.cat
INNER JOIN import_desctemp c1
ON c1.Sub1 = t.cat
)

UPDATE R
SET primary_Cat_id = c.csd
FROM Description_Category R
INNER JOIN cte c
ON c.csd = R.CSD_ID


/*--Insert primary category IDs from @table into the template category table
update Description_Category
SET Primary_Cat_Id = M.csd
FROM @MergeOutput1 M
JOIN Description_Category O ON O.CSD_ID = M.csd*/

SELECT * FROM @MergeOutput1


/*insert Description_Category (Category)
OUTPUT INSERTED.CSD_ID
select sub1
FROM import_desctemp p
left join @MergeOutput1 m on p.Main = m.cat--LEFT join is important, otherwise may not copy all rows
WHERE p.Sub1 IS NOT NULL*/

/*--Insert cst IDs from @table into the excel table
update import_desctemp
SET CST = M.csd
FROM @MergeOutput1 M
JOIN import_desctemp O ON O.Main = M.Cat
COMMIT;*/
© 2016 Microsoft Terms Privacy & cookies Developers English (United States)
```

Expected result

```html
+--------+------------+-----------+----------------+
| TempID |  Category  | Parent_id | Primary_cat_id |
+--------+------------+-----------+----------------+
|      1 | Commercial |         0 |              1 |
|     12 | Domestic   |         0 |             12 |
|     16 | Bathroom   |         1 |              1 |
|     17 | Kitchen    |         1 |              1 |
|     18 | Rumpus     |         1 |              1 |
|     19 | Bathroom   |        12 |             12 |
|     20 | Kitchen    |        12 |             12 |
|     21 | Laundry    |        12 |             12 |
+--------+------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: please check this link and see how you can improve your question :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: show us what have you tried. current and desire result, and a litle explain will also help.

Comment: Took me ages to reach to 7 points for my reputation. But its a fair call. I'll try to include all relevant data in future questions. Thanks

Comment: @Jay:please read the link ,i have given ,even though the question is basic,question  in that format will provide you fast answers and even upvotes as well

Comment: @Jay have you seen my answer? Maybe it could help you, I have posted a simple example of getting IDs you need assuming that you have some table with all categories where category name and there IDs are stored.

Comment: @gofr1 Yes I have. I tried to implement it but it didnt work. I will try and put up the schema and my merge code later on. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join table with categories (I called it `categories`) IDs with your `Table` like:

```
SELECT c1.pkid, t.sub1, c.pkid
FROM Table t 
INNER JOIN categories c
ON c.category = t.main
INNER JOIN categories c1
ON c1.category = t.sub
```

To update:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT c1.pkid, t.sub1, c.pkid as cat_id
FROM Table t 
INNER JOIN categories c
ON c.category = t.main
INNER JOIN categories c1
ON c1.category = t.sub
)

UPDATE R
SET Cat_id = c.cat_id
FROM Results R
INNER JOIN cte c
ON c.pkid = R.pkid
```